# Creating an array of view controllers?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I'm brand new when it comes to app development so this might be a stupid question.

So i have made a UI table. It is customizable, as in users can insert or delete rows. I want to allow users to click on a table cell and it'll direct them to another view controller. All the view controllers will look the same for each cell (sorta like a template). Any idea how to implement this using storyboard?

Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In storyboard you create a viewcontroller that will display the data after a cell has been selected, you will only need one and not an array. Link it from the tableviewcontroller to the new viewcontroller. Click the segue in Xcode and in the inspector give it a unique identifier.

`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will get called when you select a cell, here you can perform the segue:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  self.selectedObject = ... // store the object that was selected
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];
}
```

In your tableviewcontroller you make sure you implement `prepareForSegue:sender:`. Here you can hand over the correct model object to populate your destination viewcontroller with data.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mySegue"])
  {
    MyDetailViewCotroller  *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
    controller.dataObject = self.selectedObject;
  }
}
```

Check out this example code from Apple (does not used Storyboard though): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007416

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an array of view controllers. All you need is one view controller, which gets instantiated when the user clicks the cell to navigate to it, and gets deallocated as soon as the user closes the screen to go back to your main view controller.

All you need to implement this in your storyboard is adding a push segue from a cell or a button in your main view controller to your "detail" view controller. When the segue gets triggerred, your code gets a chance to configure the newly created "detail" view controller in the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method, before the controller's view appears on the screen. This is the place where you customize the data that shows up in the detail view (presumably, depending on the particular row in the table that has triggered the segue).

Here is a [link to a good tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) explaining how to build a master-detail application with Xcode and storyboards.